# Azure Roadmap : AspCore 3.0

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

When we deploy an ASP.CORE 3.0 on Azure we have this error:

> The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 3.0

Okay... but do you know when ASP.CORE 3.0 will be available in Azure App Service ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now its [not deployed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#aspnet-core-30-not-currently-available-for-azure-app-service) and no estimates are provided

But you should be able to do it [your self](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/azure-apps/index?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#deploy-aspnet-core-preview-release-to-azure-app-service)

Install the preview site extension

1. From the Azure Portal, navigate to the App Service.
2. Select the web app.
3. Type "ex" in the search box to filter for "Extensions" or scroll down the list of management tools.
4. Select Extensions.
5. Select Add.
6. Select the ASP.NET Core {X.Y} ({x64|x86}) Runtime extension from the list, where {X.Y} is the ASP.NET Core preview version and {x64|x86} specifies the platform.
7. Select OK to accept the legal terms.
8. Select OK to install the extension.

Answer (score 1):

The channel to get the best information about Azure Updates is:

https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements

But until now nothing has been posted there.

The MS Dev-Blog https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-core-3-0/ is saying that

> Azure App Service deployment of .NET Core 3.0 is currently ongoing.

So I suggest you set up a watch on the github repo above to get notified once the work is done.

Comment: You are welcome - if it was useful feel free to upvote it!

Answer (score 0):

Work is in progress and will be available in some time. But No ETA at this point.